# serving files from s3

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, amazon-s3, flash

I need to take the advantage of caching files at s3, I decided to put mu swf files at amazon bucket, but i get forbidden error at log of chrome

How can I have a swf file hosted at heroku to load swf file hosted at amazon bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand things correctly you might have an issue with crossdomain loading (crossdomain.xml). Please see this link for an elaborate answer on how to solve it: [Writing Flash crossdomain.xml for Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527624/writing-flash-crossdomain-xml-for-amazon-s3)

Comment: The error I get is "403 Forbidden HTTP status code" not related to cross domain issue .. its directly related to amazon s3 server

Comment: S3 issues the 403 response for two common reasons.

Either the file you're trying to access doesn't exist, or the file exists but doesn't have it's ACL setup to allow anonymous users to read the file. This can be changed through the AWS management console, S3 section.